# C# copy generic list to object with fewer columns

Tags: c#

```
public class Person
{
  public string FirstName {get; set;}
  public string LastName {get; set;}
  public string Email {get; set;}
}


public class PersonTarget
{
  public string FirstName {get; set;}
}
```

Is there an easy way to copy Person data to PersonTarget?

I'm using a foreach loop:

```
        List<Person> people = new List<Person>();
        people.Add(new Person() { FirstName = "John", LastName = "Smith", Email = "test@example.com" });

        List<PersonTarget> peopleCopy = new List<PersonTarget>();

        foreach (var person in people)
        {
            peopleCopy.Add(new PersonTarget() { FirstName = person.FirstName });
        }
```

Comment: To be honest, reflection. Libraries like AutoMapper wrap this up for you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use linq:

```
 peopleCopy = people.Select(p => new PersonTarget() {FirstName = p.FirstName}).ToList();
```

Comment: How is that easier?   Subjective as it is...